# kubernetes deployment hyperledger fabric

Tags: kubernetes, hyperledger

I am trying to deploy hyperledger fabric on Kubernetes. My local machine is on Ubuntu 16.04 and I'm using Kubernetes version 1.11.2. I created a cluster using kubeadm, using flannel for the network. I have one master and one worker node and hyperledger fabric consensus with Apache Kafka.

Here's the error I get on deployment:

```
2018-09-12 04:17:13.845 UTC [grpc] Printf -> DEBU d09 grpc: Server.Serve failed to complete security handshake from "10.244.1.1:49848": EOF
2018-09-12 04:17:15.890 UTC [grpc] Printf -> DEBU d0a grpc: Server.Serve failed to complete security handshake from "10.244.1.1:49850": EOF
2018-09-12 04:17:18.845 UTC [grpc] Printf -> DEBU d0b grpc: Server.Serve failed to complete security handshake from "10.244.1.1:49862": EOF
2018-09-12 04:17:23.845 UTC [grpc] Printf -> DEBU d0c grpc: Server.Serve failed to complete security handshake from "10.244.1.1:49878": EOF
2018-09-12 04:17:25.890 UTC [grpc] Printf -> DEBU d0d grpc: Server.Serve failed to complete security handshake from "10.244.1.1:49880": EOF
2018-09-12 04:17:28.845 UTC [grpc] Printf -> DEBU d0e grpc: Server.Serve failed to complete security handshake from "10.244.1.1:49892": EOF
2018-09-12 04:17:33.845 UTC [grpc] Printf -> DEBU d0f grpc: Server.Serve failed to complete security handshake from "10.244.1.1:49908": EOF
```

What is the problem here and how can I fix it?

Comment: Where is your cluster running?

Comment: hi, My cluster run private cloud. private cloud use KVM.

Comment: I'm fix it. tks

Comment: Good to hear that you fixed it!

Comment: Can you share how did you fix it?

Comment: Liveness is enabled for the fabric service port when the hyperledger fabric is deployed. Closing the liveness of the port solves this problem. good luck.

Comment: I understand that the reason for this error is because kubernetes need to communicate with the fabric, but the certificate cannot be caused to cause communication abnormalities.

Comment: Hopefully my answer is helpful to you